# is there any way to reduce the time "wasted" by get requests by sending data you know will be requested?

Tags: node.js, get

I have a page on my website that requires two scripts, JQuery and a custom element I made, that custom element than requests data from the server using JQuery, and it also requests a css file.
I was wandering if there was a way to minimize load times by sending the scripts, the data and the css alongside the HTML page instead of waiting for the client side to request them.

for server-side I'm using node.js with express.js, for client-side I don't have a framework, I just use JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides caching your resources (using browser built-in developer tools, like [`localStorage`](https://javascript.info/localstorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://javascript.info/localstorage)), consider making use of a compression algorithm for your assets like [gzip](https://www.gzip.org/) or [brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli) (recommended)

There were two ways to implement the compression in Express directly (without any web server i.e: apache, nginx, etc...):

- Static building of compressed files with help of Webpack (any other frontend task runner or builder) and serve them on demand as needed by client.
- Dynamic building of compressed files on the run time (You can use `require(‘compression’)`) in express to dynamically compresse files and serve to the client on the fly.

### Using Gzip

> Quoted from http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html

Gzip compressing can greatly decrease the size of the response body and hence increase the speed of a web app. Use the compression middleware for gzip [compression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) in your Express app. For example:

```js
const compression = require('compression')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(compression())
```

### Using Brotli (recommended)

> Quoted from https://codeburst.io/express-brotli-webpack-a60773e7ec6c
>
> By adhering to this method, you'll need to install [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) (module bundler)

you can include these two plugins [`compression-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression-webpack-plugin) and [`brotli-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brotli-webpack-plugin)

```js
const CompressionPlugin = require(‘compression-webpack-plugin’)
const BrotliPlugin = require(‘brotli-webpack-plugin’)
module.exports = {
   plugins: [
    new CompressionPlugin({
       asset: ‘[path].gz[query]’,
       algorithm: ‘gzip’,
       test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
       threshold: 10240,
       minRatio: 0.8
    }),
    new BrotliPlugin({
       asset: ‘[path].br[query]’,
       test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
       threshold: 10240,
       minRatio: 0.8
    })
  ]
}
```

These plugins will generate both `gzip` and `brotli` file for all of your bundles i.e if bundle name is `vendor_d0cfe49e718c1366c661.js` you will get the `vendor_d0cfe49e718c1366c661.js.gzip` and `vendor_d0cfe49e718c1366c661.js.br` in the same directory (let’s assume it is `/dist/static/vendor_d0cfe49e718c1366c661.js.*` as of now).

> **PS:** The above code will only generate the `.gzip` and `.br` if the `minRatio: 0.8` is achieved while compressing files. So in case of very small files `gzip` and `br` files will not be generated. The reason is that time in compressing and decompressing is costlier than the actual file served without compression.

Comment: localStorage seems to be a viable solution to my problem, thank you very much, I think I'll try to make a library to automate the process.